# AngularJS track by not removing $$hashKey, causing duplicate manipulation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently adding "rows" to the DOM via ng-repeat. (AngularJS 1.5)

I have a simple ng-repeat through an array within my `$scope`. I've done this many times and I've never had a problem.

Here is my ng-repeat:
`<li ng-repeat="row in panelRows track by $index" x-sb-panel-row row-data="row" class="row"></li>`

In my interface, I add 2 objects that are the same, and of course, by adding track-by, i want them to be handled individually.

Here is my object printed in the console, from my directive `x-sb-panel-row`, passed through `row-data="row"` (using isolate scope and 2 way binding through attribute `row-data`).

Row 1: `Object {name: "Test carousel (not really a carousel)", subText: "3 x 33%", columns: Array[3], $$hashKey: "object:68"}`

Row 2: `Object {name: "Test carousel (not really a carousel)", subText: "3 x 33%", columns: Array[3], $$hashKey: "object:68"}`

My problem is the `$$hashKey: "object:68"`, Apparently using `track-by` should remove this, but it doesn't, and it gives the same value to my objects. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my problem. Turns out that i was `pushing` a new row to my `$scope.panelRows`, but the object i was pushing was an object already parsed by angularjs, with its own $$hashKey.

Therefor, angularjs thought he was pushing the same object many times.

Before:
`$scope.panelRows.push(col)`

After:

`$scope.panelRows.push(angular.copy(col))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, searched long and hard for a solution.

Note this will also work when using `unshift()`